# Как пользоваться user-agent?

Tags: javascript, useragent

Мне стало интересно - как получить из user-agent только тот браузер,  из которого я получаю информацию?

Пишу : `let ua = window.navigator.userAgent;`

Проверяю : `console.log(ua)`

Получаю список : `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"`

Но мне нужен только мой браузер, а ни все, которые существуют.
Как получить только тот, в котором я нахожусь?

Comment: Проверять наличие или отсутствие в userAgent слов, характерных для интересующего браузера

Comment: @andreymal да я понял - это - только всё что я делаю не работает

Comment: Уже всё сделано за нас, гуглится полно готовых решений https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за ссылку - я в своём ответе нашёл что то - вроде работает но в edge нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Единственное что я нагуглил

```js
navigator.sayswho = (function() {
  var ua = navigator.userAgent,
    tem,
    M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
  if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
    tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
    return 'IE ' + (tem[1] || '');
  }
  if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
    tem = ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
    if (tem != null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
  }
  M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
  if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
  return M.join(' ');
})();

console.log(navigator.sayswho)

user.innerHTML = navigator.sayswho
```

```html
<div id="user"> </div>
```